# In Hebrew, what is this suffix ending that is on the nouns in psalm 103:3?

Tags: hebrew, psalms

What is the suffix ending on the words for iniquities and diseases? (the Kauf,chirriq,yod ending)  I see it is interpreted as 'thy' but this is not the usual possessive ending for 'your'.   (I am a student with only 1 year study,  thank you for your help)

הַסֹּלֵחַ לְכָל־**עֲוֹנֵכִי** הָרֹפֵא לְכָל־**תַּחֲלֻאָֽיְכִי**׃

Comment: There is now [an exact duplicate](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/8652/2215) of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed an unusual form of the 2nd person feminine singular suffix. Rest assured it is an exception, but carries no special meaning. It does however appear elsewhere in scripture, for example Psalms 116:7 and weakly in Kings II 4:3,7. Gesenius 91l considers most similar unusual suffixes of this nature probably scribal error. Although this particular form he notes is similar to the Syriac. It seems possible that it isn't a mistake, but generous poetic licence.