# Psa. 103:4: חַיָּיְכִי and הַמְעַטְּרֵכִי

Tags: hebrew, psalms

What is the explanation for the כי- suffix on the words חַיָּיְכִי and הַמְעַטְּרֵכִי in [Psa. 103:4](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?b=Psa&c=103&v=1&t=KJV#conc/4)?

Comment: It turns out [this has been asked before](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/5674/2215). Must be a good question. ;)

Comment: @Davïd: Ha wow! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  כִי- (*-kî*) 2nd fem sg suffix (which appears also in vv. 3 and 5) is explained as simply a rare (or possibly [Aramaizing](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WHtcQB6_xLQC&lpg=PA66&pg=PA66#v=onepage&q&f=false)) form of the suffix: see Gesenius Kautzsch Cowley, [§58g (for the verb)](https://archive.org/stream/geseniushebrewgr00geseuoft#page/156/mode/1up) and [§91e for the noun](https://archive.org/stream/geseniushebrewgr00geseuoft#page/256/mode/1up). Basically the same explanation is given in [Joüon-Muraoka](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=s1MSQuK_gi0C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), at §61i (verb), and §94i (noun). See also p. 269 of Geoffrey Khan's discussion of pronominal suffixes from the *Encyclopedia of Hebrew Language and Linguistics*, ed G. Khan et al. (Brill, 2013), [Vol. 3, pp.267-272](http://www.brill.com/downloads/COM-00000444_Pronominal%20Suffixes_267-272.pdf).

It is a *feminine* suffix because the psalmist is "speaking to" his *nephesh*, "soul" ("Bless the LORD, O my *soul*...", 103:1-2), and "soul" is grammatically feminine, and the antecedent of all these 2nd fem sg pronouns in vv. 3-5.